# Pass several lists of columns to index a dataframe (without using loc/iloc)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Perhaps a duplicate, but I couldn't find relevant answers on SO. Please consider:

Create df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Greenland'],
    'color': ['Blue', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green', 'Purple'],
    'level': ['High', 'Low', 'Low', 'High', 'Low'],
    'random': ['df', 'adsf', 'wqer', 'qewr', 'ycxb'],
    'number': [1, 3, 5, 7, 1]})
df
```

Out:

```
   id   country    color  level random  number
0   1   USA        Blue   High  df      1
1   2   USA        Blue   Low   adsf    3
2   3   Canada     Red    Low   wqer    5
3   4   Canada     Green  High  qewr    7
4   5   Greenland  Purple Low   ycxb    1
```

We can create list of columns to index our df. For example:

```
numeric = ['id', 'number']
df[numeric]
```

Out:

```
    id  number
0   1   1
1   2   3
2   3   5
3   4   7
4   5   1
```

But now let's say we create a second list of columns:

```
list2 = ['country', 'level']
```

And we try to retrieve variables using **both** lists:

```
df[[numeric, list2]]
```

This does not work.

My question: how do you use both (or more) lists to index the df? I have hundreds of variables so cannot write them all as a list using traditional `df.loc` method, for example. Is there a simple solution?

Desired output:

```
    id  number  country    level
0   1   1       USA        High
1   2   3       USA        Low
2   3   5       Canada     Low
3   4   7       Canada     High
4   5   1       Greenland  Low
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `df[numeric+list2]` ?

Comment: Argh... so easy I overlooked that! thank you, anky

Comment: @anky, I'm new here just wondering why answer in comments though?

Comment: @Abhi_J it is a duplicate and has been asked before. OP knew how to subset based on a list , however didnot consider concating the lists to subset. this has been asked before, hence I have closed as duplicate

Comment: @anky oh ok got it, thanks